# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code=2 while using service

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my application i am using a background service,
Here is its basic code

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


Service contains some timers


public class ConnectionService extends Service
{
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ConnectionServiceBinder();
    private MyApplication app;

    private CountDownTimer mAliveTimer;
    public CountDownTimer  mPanicTimer;
    public CountDownTimer  mPerodicTimer;

    /* Not using binder anywhere right now */
    public class ConnectionServiceBinder extends Binder
    {
        public ConnectionService getService()
        {
            return ConnectionService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        //connect();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void createPerodicTimer()
    {
        if (mPerodicTimer != null)
            mPerodicTimer.cancel();

        float fastestInterval = Preferences.getFloatSharedPrefValue(app, Constants.USERDEFAULT_SETTINGS_TIME, 5f) * 60 * 1000;
        mPerodicTimer = new CountDownTimer((int)fastestInterval, 1000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                Location myLocation = app.myLocationProvider.getMyLocation();
                Location currentBestLocation = null;
                String locValue = Preferences.getSharedPrefValue(app, Constants.USERDEFAULT_LOCATION);
                if (locValue != null)
                {
                    currentBestLocation = new Gson().fromJson(locValue, Location.class);
                }

                if (currentBestLocation == null)
                {
                    sendPerodicReporting();
                    Preferences.saveSharedPrefValue(app, Constants.USERDEFAULT_LOCATION , new Gson().toJson(myLocation));
                }
                else
                {
                    float displacement = Preferences.getFloatSharedPrefValue(app, Constants.USERDEFAULT_SETTINGS_DISTANCE, 50);
                    float dist = myLocation.distanceTo(currentBestLocation);
                    if (dist >= displacement)
                    {
                        sendPerodicReporting();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ApiManager.getInstance().mDbHelper.addToLog("System Event", "Perodic Report not sent", "Distance travelled is less than set displacement settings" + dist + " < " + displacement, app);
                    }
                }

                Preferences.saveSharedPrefValue(app, Constants.USERDEFAULT_LOCATION , new Gson().toJson(myLocation));
                mPerodicTimer.start();
            }
        };

        mPerodicTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.mService = this;
        app.addLocationUpdates();
        createPerodicTimer();

        mAliveTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000 * 60, 1000) // Keep Alive Timer is 30 minutes
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                if (Preferences.getBoolSharedPrefValue(app.getApplicationContext(), Constants.USERDEFAULT_SETTINGS_ALIVE, false))
                    sendAliveResponse();

                if (Preferences.getBoolSharedPrefValue(app.getApplicationContext(), Constants.USERDEFAULT_IS_PANIC_ENABLED, false))
                    sendPanicReporting();

                mAliveTimer.start();
            }
        };

        mPanicTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) // Keep Alive Timer is 30 seconds
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                if (Preferences.getBoolSharedPrefValue(app.getApplicationContext(), Constants.USERDEFAULT_IS_PANIC_ENABLED, false))
                {
                    sendPanicReporting();
                    mPanicTimer.start();
                }
            }
        };

        mAliveTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

Sometimes after the application, let's say after a min i get crash

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code=2
I have tried searching for a solution but can't find anything to work.

if i remove service from my app, app works fine.

What should i do to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Please post the complete error and stack if available

Comment: @SagiLow Please check

Comment: There is no more info? Have you tried adding some log prints to see where it happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure (it's a little bit hard to figure out what happened without full stack trace), but try to disable saving of shared preferences in the service and check if application fails. I think that this problem may be caused by strings produced by Gson serialized.

I checked implementation of JsonElement returned by line

```
new Gson().toJson(...)
```

and it seems that it does not implement **java.io.Serializable** interface. This may cause the problem during object save.

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem, tho i fixed it before, but for future references for anyone :). It works if i debug but not sure why sometimes it fails